# how to pull Zendesk tickets data using python?

Tags: python, zendesk, zendesk-api

I want to export all Zendesk Tickets data using Python. The data should be in csv format, and should include all fields related to tickets.

Is there any way we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Python library for the Zendesk API and it has a bulk export feature for tickets and other objects - http://docs.facetoe.com.au/zenpy.html#incremental-exports. Once you have the tickets writing the data to a CSV should be straightforward. Eg:

```
for ticket in zenpy.tickets.incremental(start_time=somedate):
    ... do stuff with ticket
```

Comment: Does your API has the ability to update a zendesk ticket with data from PostgreSQL database? It would be very helpful if you can guide on this.